# In an Ember handlebars template, ".active" styling does not stick

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am working on an Ember project and noticed some weird behavior. I am using `{{link-to}}` helpers to build all my in-app links, and when I am on the correct page the navigation links correctly have an `active` class assigned.

What I noticed, however, is that the styling only persists until I click on the page. When I click on anything else, the styling goes away, however the class seems to remain.

Is there anything that I am possibly missing? I am pretty new to Ember, and most of my work has been on web pages that have little AJAX content, so it is entirely possible I am missing something super simple.

Thank you,

### Update

It was pointed out that I did not include any examples, but truth is the application is extremely basic. I just started coding it and noticed this behavior.

The only things I have done are:

1. Create a new Ember app with ember-cli with `ember new timeclock` (the name of my application)
2. Include Iconic.js and Bootstrap in my `Brocfile.js` (For Iconic.js I just copied the files into the `vendor` directory. For bootstrap I am using `ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy` add-on).

I have an initializer called `initialize-assets.js` with the content (to make Iconic.JS load properly):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default {
  name: 'initialize-assets',
  initialize: function() {
    Ember.Route.reopen({
      renderTemplate: function() {
        this._super();
        var initResources = function() {
          new IconicJS().inject('img.iconic');
        };
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', initResources);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I also have a custom route that I defined to enable Iconic.js to work properly:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate : function() {
    this.render();
    var myfunction=function() {
       new IconicJS().inject('img.iconic');
    };
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', initializeAssets);
  }
});
```

Here is the `application.hbs` content:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      {{link-to 'Timeclock' 'index' class='navbar-brand'}}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="wrapper" {{bind-attr class='menuToggled'}}>
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li>
        <a {{action 'toggleMenu'}}>
          <img data-direction="left" data-head="line-large" data-src="icons/arrow-thick.svg" class="iconic iconic-sm" />
          Toggle Menu
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'index' class="active"}}
        <img data-src="icons/home.svg" class="iconic iconic-sm" />
        Home
        {{/link-to}}
      </li>
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'group.index'}}
        <img data-src="icons/people.svg" class="iconic iconic-sm" />
        Groups
        {{/link-to}}
      </li>
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'user.index'}}
        <img data-gender="genderless" data-src="icons/person.svg" class="iconic iconic-sm" />
        Users
        {{/link-to}}
      </li>
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'event.index'}}
        <img data-src="icons/list.svg" class="iconic iconic-sm" />
        Events
        {{/link-to}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `{{link-to}}` tags set the "active" class properly, and the styling shows (but only until I click something else).

Comment: Without any code or example can't really help you

Comment: have you tried turning off ionic or bootstrap to see if any of them is causing the problem? is the 'active' class removed from element, or just the styling is overwritten?

Comment: The class remains, however the style disappears (according to Chrome inspector). I have commented out Bootstrap and Iconic.JS in the SCSS and added a dummy selector `.active { background: red; }` and it works as expected. Adding Iconic.JS back seems to still allow it to work. So perhaps a Bootstrap issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help, but it appears I was sleep-deprived when I posted this.

My SCSS styles were using the `:active` selector. I needed to add an `.active` selector. The colon and period looked too similar when I was going through this with no sleep last night. When I added the selector to the applicable rules, everything worked out.